# Error in using .attrTween within enter function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am attempting to make a reusable chart in D3. The figure draws a line using `.curve(d3.curveStepAfter)` and I am attempting to animate the lines using the stroke-dasharray attribute with a tween function. The following code is how I initialize the visualization:

```
selection
  .append('g')
  .selectAll('path.line')
  .data(grouped_data)
  .join(
    (enter) => enter
       .append('path')
       .attr('class', 'step_line')
       .call(initializeLine)
       .call(lineTransition),
    (update) => update,
    (exit) => exit.remove());
```

```
const initilizeLine = (enter) => {
    enter
      .attr('d', (d) => drawCurve(d[1]))
      .attr('stroke', d => {
              return color(d[0]);
        })
      .attr('fill', 'none');
}

const lineTween = () => {
  let l = this.getTotalLength(),
      i = d3.interpolateString('0,' + l, l + ',' + l);
  return function(t) { return i(t) };
}

const lineTransition = (enter) => {
    enter
      .transition()
      .duration(2500)
      .attrTween('stroke-dasharray', lineTween);
}
```

The lines draw correctly in the svg, but the transition doesn't work. When I look in the console I see the error this.getTotalLength is not a function. This is because the enter object is being passed. I need to be able to pass the path to the lineTween function, but am scratching my head.

Comment: I get a similar result with this code - "this.node is not a function". When I console log the this object in the lineTween function, it prints the window object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context of your arrow function `this` is the `window`. Therefore, either use a regular function or use the third and second parameters combined to get the element you want:

```
const lineTween = (_, j, n) => {
  let l = n[j].getTotalLength(),
      i = d3.interpolateString('0,' + l, l + ',' + l);
  return function(t) { return i(t) };
}
```